# Why is my Google App script ignoring rows when it logically has no reason to?

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote some code to filter out rows of data from a master sheet and put them into a new sheet if the data falls between a particular date. For example, if I want all the rows that have information from "3/1/2023 - 3/31/2023", I click run, and my software filters the master data sheet and gives me just the rows that meet the criteria.

Here is the problem:
For some reason, my code pulls all the correct rows, except for the rows whose dates fall between "3/4/2023 - 3/9/2023". If I change the dates to any other date except "3/4/2023 - 3/9/2023", the data will appear in the other sheet.

I don't understand why this is happening? Here is a link to the spreadsheet so you can make your own copy and try the code out yourself: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wZuC8rp02uni81qseA2GA10Q2y5YFHMu-DVHmiCReMQ/edit?usp=sharing

Also my code is provided below. Any help and clarity would be appreciated. Thanks!

Apps script code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

// creates new sheeet with formula that pulls the desired billing data from data source
function newSheet(){
  
  ss.insertSheet(2).setName('Bill');

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  
  sheet.getRange("A3").activate()
  .setFormula('=FILTER(\'Billing Master Sheet\'A2:C,\'Billing Master Sheet\'!A2:A >=\"3/1/2023"'+',\'Billing Master Sheet\'!A2:A <=\"3/31/2023"' +')');

}

function billGenerator(){

 newSheet();
}
```

Comment: You are comparing to a string, you need to compare to a `DATE(2023,3,1)` for example.